# Debugging JNLP security problems

Tags: java, oracle, security, java-web-start, jnlp

The error message generally produced by JNLP clients, not least Sun's/Oracle's own Java Web Start client, are generally oriented towards end-users and not very helpful for figuring out the root cause for why they appear.

For instance, when I try to run my JNLP program right now with Oracle's JNLP client, it simply says to me that "The Java security settings have prevented this application from running. You may change this behavior in the Java Control Panel." NetX hasn't been much more helpful either, but it also seems to implement much less of the security model than Oracle's client does, so it would only help so far even if it were.

Is there any good way to find out what security problems it is that I'm actually having? "Read the documentation" is of course the easy answer, but the security model seems rather complex and incorporates many parts. Is there some kind of "lint" tool for JNLP out there that can list the problems I'm having? Or is there some way to run the JNLP client in some kind of debug mode?

I'm not really asking for help with this particular, specific problem. I've been having other problems previously, too, and have mostly only gotten past them by mere guess-work and getting lucky, and I'm still not sure I've solved them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to debug the Web Start using [-Xdebug](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/faq.html#debug)

Also this [link](https://www.java.net/node/688563) might be useful if there is any issue while enabling debug